# How to add my askubuntu points widgets to blogger?

Tags: discussion, support

I read somewhere (please don't ask me where as I have forgotten) that I could add my profile points to blogger so as to show that you are indeed a member of the community (ask Ubuntu ). Can someone please help me with a guide to make this happen on my soon-to-be-launched blog on blogger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://askubuntu.com/users/12846/mysterio?tab=flair

It's called Flair! They're static images that get updated every so often, instructions on how to add it to your page are included in the above link.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please I'm a newbie to blogger so where do I place the HTML code in blogger and also will this work on a custom template?

Comment: @Mysterio You may want to ask that question on [Webapps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com)